# Importing products via Feeds csv import is generating error: "General error: 1366 Incorrect string value:"

Tags: feeds, commerce, importing-exporting

I'm trying to import products using the import via csv functionality within feeds and am getting the following errors:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xB7 The ...' for column 'field_description_value' at row 1
Error message SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xB7 The ...' for column 'message' at row 1
```

I also have the commerce-feeds module installed.

There is quite a lot of stuff on this on drupal.org, but it all seems to be contradictory and I am more than a little lost. I am a non-coder and a relatively inexperienced configurator at best.

My csv is definitely encoded UTF-8. I have opened it in Notepad++ and converted it to UTF-8.

I found this post on stack overflow [utf-8 database problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615611/utf-8-database-problem) The line "It seems your connection is not set to UTF8 but some other 8 bit encoding like ISO Latin" seems to indicate to me that there may be a bug in the Feeds or Commerce Feeds modules in that the database connection cannot cope with csv input files encoded UTF-8. Could that be correct?

I'd really appreciate some sage advice on this. I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the csv is encoded in UTF8, but everything else needs to be UTF8: [UTF8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

I don't know exactly in what step is failing, did you check the databases and tables collation?
Drupal has by default the "SET NAMES="utf8", http://drupal.org/node/310447

Hopefully the Feeds maintainers have a look to your case here. http://drupal.org/node/1140194 , it seems you are not alone.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to respond. I'm quite embarrassed but I actually started the whole process again starting with the original excel file, save to csv, pull in to notepad++, change the encoding to UTF-8, and then import; and now the import process is working fine. 

The bounty is all yours though except the system says I have to wait for 21 hours before I can do that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure your question will help other people with same problem.